Are all types of infinite expansions of functions on a compact interval into polynomials equivalent?
If I expand a function $f(x)$ into an infinite sum of polynomials, according to any given set of rules, i.e. Taylor series, Legendre polynomials, or other types of polynomial expansion, if the function is continous on this compact interval and can be expanded into these various types of polynomial expansions, are the coefficients of these expansions term by term equivalent?
If they're not, then the difference of two different expansions wouldn't be zero, and thus they would be expanding different functions.
What's the error here?

this is quite a vague question since you need to define what expansion means; in general, you need some kind of uniformity in the convergence to deduce equality of coefficients (note that the uniformity may automatically come from the expansion type like in the Taylor series case), but in general, the answer is no if you just have pointwise convergence - one can show using complex analysis methods that $0=\sum_k P_k(x)$ pointwise in the whole plane for nonzero polynomials $P_k$ with strictly increasing degrees so no finite subsum of them is identically zero
